# unable to import 'pandas_ta' library to AWS Lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda-layers, pandas-ta

Im using 'pandas_ta' library in my code. the program runs fine in my local system.
However, when trying to deploy the same code in AWS Lambda after adding 'pandas_ta' as an layer, the code throws an error as

"Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pandas_ta'"

Could anyone guide me on fixing this issue

Thanks